# Type narrowing a deeply nested object

Tags: typescript, axios

I'm trying to drill down through an unknown shaped object at runtime. What I'm confused about is that I'm getting an `Unsafe member access .errors on an any value` error on all the references below `if (typeof err.response?.data === "object")`. However, shouldn't data be narrowed at that point to an object which has an errors property?

```
const getApiError = (err) => {
  if (axios.isAxiosError(err)) {
    if (typeof err.response?.data === "object") {
      if ("errors" in err.response?.data)
        if (
          Array.isArray(err.response?.data.errors) &&
          err.response?.data.errors.length > 0
        ) {
          return err.response?.data.errors[0] as ApiError
        }
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

Also, if there's a more elegant way to drill down through objects like this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first part of your question. Type narrowing right now [works only on the level](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758#issuecomment-332273961) the discriminating property is on. So narrowing the type to `object | null` with `typeof err.response?.data === 'object'` doesn't affect neither `err` nor `err.response` types.

As for the practical example. Since you need result only in the form of `ApiError | null` you may omit intermediate steps and get right to the business:

```ts
const getApiError = (err: unknown): ApiError | null => {
    if (!axios.isAxiosError(err)) return null
    const errors = (err as AxiosError<{ errors: ApiError[] }>).response?.data?.errors

    return Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0
        ? errors[0]
        : null
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRpdnm)

Comment: I still get `Unsafe member access .errors on 'any' value` on line 3.

Comment: Can you provide your concrete example at [typescript playgroun](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?

Comment: Oh, I got the problem. That's `typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-memeber-access` rule. Updated the answer.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks.